# How to combine MROUND to if then formula

Tags: excel, rounding

I’m trying to find a way I could insert the MROUND into my if then formula to round up to the nearest 5.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H6),
    " ",
    (IF(H6="% Top Set",
        G6*R6,
        IF(H6="% Today E1RM",
           G6*T6,
           IF(H6="% Previous Set",
              G6*N5,
              IF(U6="Comp Squat",
                 G6*SquatPR,
                 IF(U6="Comp Bench",
                    G6*BenchPR,
                    IF(U6="Comp Deadlift",
                       G6*DeadliftPR,
                       " "
                      )
                   )
                )
             )
          )
       )
    )
   )
```

Comment: I have no clue what your formula does, but round to 5 is easy. `Round(X/5,0)*5`

Comment: My formula is for certain drop down menus when I plug in a value. That formula doesn’t work for me

Comment: Your formula, even after formatting, is so complex that I'd advise you to write a user-defined function for it in VBA.